# Mod rewrite, redirect all to https except specific URI and redirect that URI from https to http

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

So I've been hitting a wall have have tried many different options, and configurations. I'm trying to redirect my site to https with the exception of one specific URI which I want to be redirected from https to http and then remain http. I would greatly appreciate any help. This is being done from the virtualhost configuration. Below are the settings I have tried in pairs with ssl.conf and mysite.conf. However I keep either getting a redirect loop or a page that doesn't load.

mysite.conf

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.site.com$1 [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/|page1|page2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.site.com$1 [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.site.com$1 [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my.site.com$1 [R,L]
```

Plus one of the above.

Then in ssl.conf

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my.site.com$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you.  Place the most specific rule (that for `/example`) first.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^/?example$ http://my.site.com/example [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?example$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://my.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should work in either server (.conf) or directory (.htaccess) context.

Comment: This worked however there was an additional issue that I was able to note once I used the configuration, there was an additional URI which was being called which was not part of the exlcuded list adding the addtional Conditional statement worked. Thank you Mike.